# Get rid of "animal man/woman" corpses

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My fort and surroundings get littered by kea, raven, grasshopper, louse, dingo, etc man/woman corpses. Sadly, there is no way to butcher them for meat, if I am wrong them I am all ears. Is there a way I can get rid of all the "M" and "K" on the map, and i don't mean putting them in the refuge stockpile. Or even better, is there a way to play without these new creature types since in the previous patch I never encountered them. Of course in case of the latter i'd like to have normal versions appear instead so i can butcher them like i used to do.

I really get invested by them with almost constant amounts of 2 types roaming my map only to reappear minutes after i killed them.

Comment: I've actually got a ruby GEM that should remove all of the animalmens. Let me upload it to df mod place and drop you a link.

Comment: Here you go, Menno: http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=7996 Let me know how it works for you! It'll prevent worlds from generating with any kind of Animal man at all.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't like the possible side effect. There is a c_variation_default.txt, in it is [CREATURE_VARIATION:ANIMAL_PERSON] which generates all animal-men. Just putting [CV_REMOVE_TAG:CAN_LEARN] makes them bucherable. Now i am fiddling there with the frequenzy tag which is generating good results:
[CV_REMOVE_TAG:FREQUENCY]
[CV_NEW_TAG:FREQUENCY:5]
I will be posting this as an answer later.

Comment: Understood; I just happened to have it handy. Uploading that GEM to dffd involved minimal effort, so no worries if it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Animal-men have the [CAN_LEARN] tag. This means they are sapient creatures and dwarfs cannot butcher or eat them. To get rid of them, leave them in a corpse stockpile until they rot into bones. You can still use their bones for crafts/bolts/etc.

If you want to remove them altogether, you could delete them from the raws. Go to the folder where Dwarf Fortress is and go to raw/objects. Most of the animal men are in creature_subteranean. Either remove the [CAN_LEARN] tag so you can butcher them or remove the entry altogether.

Note that you may have to start a new region for these changes to take effect. **Backup any files before you change them.**

Comment: You need to update the raw in the save foleder to make them effective in a existing game. I tried to find this but did not know it was the [CAN_LEARN] tag, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As the man/woman part of the creature name mentions, those beings are at least borderline sentient and can therefore not be butchered for meat. Your best bet is putting up a corpse stockpile and letting the bodies rot away naturally over time, or set up one of several garbage destruction mechanisms ([magma pit garbage dump](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Garbage_dump), [dwarven atom smasher](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Dwarven_atom_smasher), etc)

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution to your problem is the Dwarves Best Friend: Magma. Toss their sorry corpses into magma or lava. And to someone above, the sapient tag may prevent butchering, but if the elves bring tame animal people to trade, you can slaughter and eat them. Tiger man meat tasts soo good.

Comment: This was not about getting rid of the corpses. The settings as they currently are bring in a lot less meat since the previous version. Pretty much no more regular or giant animals appear in some games. The best solution is the one i posted as a comment, editing the frequency creates less of the animal men and there for more regular and giant variants visit your map.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for future forts (as it requires a regen of the world) is to change dwarven ethics to allow eating of sapient creatures. To do so, open `raw/objects/entity_default.txt` and change `UNTHINKABLE` next to `ETHIC:EAT_SAPIENT_OTHER` and `ETHIC:EAT_SAPIENT_KILL` to `ACCEPTABLE` for `[ENTITY:MOUNTAIN]`.

Note that this will result in less wars with elves and more wars with humans. On the other hand, you will be able to "go green", processing not only the goblins' equipment but their bodies as well.

Comment: I like the answer of Studoku better, it results in only the animal man/woman to be "butcherable". Other then that i experimented in the past with editing the raws, and to let them effect an existing game you should edit the raws in the save folder. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MennoGouw That's true, but removing these animal men's ability to learn makes them significantly less deadly, which may make the game less enjoyable. Besides, the corpses of animal men are treated exactly the same way as the corpses of all other sentient creatures, so if one is annoyed with animal men corpses, one is likely to be equally annoyed with goblin/elven corpses.

Comment: According to  the wiki animal man are exactly the same as the giant versions except you can not butcher them. Having the [CAN_LEARN] tag does not make a creature tougher. Also there seems to be a bug with the amount of these animal man creatures generated therefore i chosen to lower the amount of these animal men amount/frequency generated which is very successful. When i have time i put that here as my own answer.

Comment: [CAN_LEARN] means they can develop skills. The difference between a novice and a legendary axedwarf lies in [CAN_LEARN].

Comment: The thing is, i never seen a animal man wield any weapon or armor. Still it's dodge, wrestling and other unarmed combat should increase IF they can but this is not the case since they enter the map "fresh" without these skills. It would be different if they would kill all my cattle and dwarfs and learn from that.

The wiki states at different animal man/woman types that they are nothing more then an un-butcherable giant version. If you check the raws they do not have personality nor are they like any other humanoid creature yet, so they might not even posses skills "yet".